# The use of Cauchy Goursat Theorem for a contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

[image]

I have been attempting this question for some time.

My reason is as follow:

The contour C (−i, −2 − i, −2 −4i, −4i) is a rectangle on the left of the Imaginary axis (vertical axis).

For any z inside and on the contour C, $Re(z) >= -2$ but  $Re(z) <=0$

Moreover, $Re(Log(z)) = ln(z) <= \ln|-2-4i| = \ln(2\sqrt(5))$.

And $Re(Log(z)) = \ln(z) >= ln|0 - i| = 0$

Can I conclude that there is a point where $z + Log(z) = 0$ ?

Because of that, $z + Log(z)$ is not analytic on $[-2, 0]$, which is inside the contour X. This means the function $\frac{\sin(z)}{z + Log(z)}$ is not analytic everywhere inside and on the contour C.

By the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, can I justify that $\int_y\frac{\sin(z)}{z + Log(z)} \neq 0$ ?

Comment: No, you cannot even come close to concluding $z + \log z = 0$ at any point from that. Also [-2, 0] is not in your contour, whose imaginary components are all -1 or less.

Comment: Hi, for the real number line, wouldn't the contour contain [-2, 0] ?

Comment: And since Log(z) is not analytic on $(-\infty, 0)$, where $[-2, 0]$ belong to $(-\inf, 0)$, can I say that this contour integral is not 0?

Comment: The real interval [-2,0] consists of points with imaginary component 0. Your contour, and its interior consists of points with imaginary components between -4 and -1. [-2, 0] is well outside

Comment: I see. I kind of understand now. So in this case, the contour integral is still 0.

Comment: I don't know. I haven't yet determined if $z + \log z$ has any roots inside it. It might be easier to look for roots of $e*{-z} = z$ instead, and see if any of them has a logarithm inside the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. Initially, I got the position of the contour wrongly